# when I click on the div that div should get refreshed and refreshed data should be displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j('.refresh').click(refreshDiv);

    j('.refresh').css({

        color: ""

    });

    function refreshDiv() {

        j.ajax({

            url: "refresh.php",

            cache: true,

            success: function (html) {

                j(".refresh").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have this code ,but I am confused how to display that div gets refreshed.Please provide me some code or links to refer.I am making site in which I want to update the score when I refresh the div using ajax.

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax request specify `dataType:'html'` as shown :-

```
 j.ajax({
        url: "refresh.php",
        dataType:"html",
        cache: true,
        success: function (html) {
            j(".refresh").html(html);
        }
 });
```

Comment: can you provide me the sample code.M new in dis field.

Comment: You may not want to cache the request either.

Comment: yes,but what can I do if I want to display how many time the page gets refreshed.foreg.if I click for the first time it should display ...page refreshed once and so on.....what should be the code in refresh.php and how to fetch it.

Comment: @nileshsurve...now you are asking a whole new question in comment **what should be the code in refresh.php**...this is not the way of asking question just show us what you have tried and then we will try to help you out...

Comment: <?php

echo time();
?>
I have this in my refresh.php ...this displays secs when I click on refresh button but it works like counter.I dont want it I want to develop like it should show properly that div is being refreshed which even a layman can understand that a div is refreshed.

Comment: sir,thats what m saying I dont want counter or display time or any thing I just want to show div gets refreshed with data

Comment: @nileshsurve...i understand...but you can use the code in fiddle as per your requirement...just you have to play with jquery a little...

Answer (score 0):

You can user the different state of Ajax please refre [Ajax Details Desc](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/)

Then put `beforeSend()` function put any loading gif img

Then on `complete()` hide or remove that image

and on success return the data to div.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your function in global scope and add the relevant datatype:

```
 function refreshDiv() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "refresh.php",
        datatype:"html",
        cache: true,
        success: function (html) {
             $(".refresh").html(html);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.refresh').click(refreshDiv);
    $('.refresh').css({
        color: ""
    });
});
```

---

Another suggestion is try replacing `$` with your `j` which you have used for `jQuery.noConflict()` utility.

---

#### [A small demo could help you.](http://plnkr.co/edit/joG3gmlwtDijcw4HCG1P?p=preview)